# What is the default activation function of cudnnlstm in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

What's the default activation function of `cudnnlstm` in TensorFlow? How can I set an activation function such as `relu`? Maybe it's just linear model? I read the document, but I did not find it.

For example, the code is below:

```
lstmcell=tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM(1,encoder_size,direction="bidirectional")

hq,_ =lstmcell(query)
```

And I read the document of TensorFlow [From this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cudnn_rnn/CudnnLSTM?hl=zh-cn).

The function is below

```
__init__(

    num_layers,
    num_units,
    input_mode=CUDNN_INPUT_LINEAR_MODE,
    direction=CUDNN_RNN_UNIDIRECTION,
    dropout=0.0,
    seed=None,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    kernel_initializer=None,
    bias_initializer=None,
    name=None
)
```

And no keyword to set a parameter such as `"activation = "tanh"` just like `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMell`.

So what's the default activation function of `cudnnlstm` in TensorFlow, and how to change it to `leaky_relu`.

Comment: To get good answers to your question, it is better to share your code to help us to help you.

Comment: Rephrased, put title also into body

Answer (score 1):

```
tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM() : Tanh
```

This was given in the Keras github.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8510#issuecomment-429255318

Nvidia documentation.

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/optimizing-recurrent-neural-networks-cudnn-5/

Answer (score 1):

To answer OP's 2nd question which was edited in later, there is [currently no way to set a custom activation function for CudnnLSTM and CudnnGRU](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24375#issuecomment-452122121).